# IE blocking file download with SSL connections - CacheControl issue

Tags: java, internet-explorer, web-applications, https

Sorry if this appears repetitive but I've been all over the interwebz looking for a satisfactory answer to this.

IE 8 (well 6 and 7 as well) is not allowing downloading files over a https based connection.

I understand this is a cache-control issue as suggested in the MS support website

and i've tried everything from setting cache-control to disabling pragma in the response header as suggested in the below links

- [Internet Explorer Cannot Download https://something](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx)
- [Internet Explorer Can't Open Files Via HTTPS: Try Removing The Pragma Header](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/internet-explorer-cant-open-file-via-https-try-removing-the-pragma-header.html)

and i am still unable to solve the issue.

I would prefer something other than a browser fix or a registry change.

My code in java looks as follows

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myXLS.xls");
response.addHeader("Cache-control", "public");
response.addHeader("Pragma", "public");
```

Appreciate the help. thanks

Comment: What is the error or message IE giving ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/OozMI I can get it to work on IE by doing this registry hack http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308 but without, doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at response headers - most likely your web server is setting some headers related to caching for this type of file. First thing I would do is to request this URL say with 'wget', let it print response headers and see what's there.

Comment: thanks, I saw that cache-control was being set as no-cache,no-store,no-cache instead of just no-store,no-cache. So, I just edited the code to                                          `response.reset(); response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myXLS.xls");
response.addHeader("Cache-control", "no-store,no-cache");`