# "page cannot be displayed" error during file upload in IE only

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, ssl

We are facing "page cannot be displayed" error during file upload in IE in our application hosted over internet, no issue with other browsers, we have allowed only TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2.. The web server is 2.2.31 Apache and cipher suite is SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

Comment: You need a lot more details for this to be a solvable thing by anything other than guessing.  One thing that immediately comes to mind is that something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476772/ie-blocking-file-download-with-ssl-connections-cachecontrol-issue

Comment: Hi All, Issue seems to be solved, here the issue is related to TCP connection timeout on uploading error records for more than 5 mins, then settings needs to be done to allow web server to maintain connection on IE, chrome and mozilla maintains that connection beyond 5 mins(max time required for maintaining TCP connection ). Please correct me if i miss anything or any correction from my side. Thanks